# How to post a Request to Web API as Xml using RestSharp?

Tags: c#, asp.net, post, action, asp.net-web-api

How to post a Request to Web API as Xml?

I'm using the below test:

```
[TestMethod]
        public void Should_post_successfully_with_valid_userDetailsList_usingRestSharp()
        {
            // arrange
            string url = string.Format("{0}/User/BulkLoad", this._baseUrlForLuis);

            var client = new RestClient(url);

            var request = new RestRequest(Method.POST)
                {
                    RequestFormat = DataFormat.Xml
                };

            request.AddBody("<user></user>");

             request.AddHeader("Accept", "application/xml");

            // act
            IRestResponse response = client.Execute<HttpResponseMessage>(request);

            Assert.AreEqual(HttpStatusCode.OK, response.StatusCode);
        }
```

and my action looks like below; it accepts a string:

```
        [HttpPost]
        public HttpResponseMessage BulkLoad([FromBody] string userDetailsListXml)
        {
}
```

But userDetailsListXml is always null so the value is not passed over.

How to fix it?

I tried with Ajax Post and the below code gets passed and works fine:

```
$.post("http://www.domain.com/User/BulkLoad", {"" : "<user></user>"});
```

But how to make it work with RestSharp?

Answer (score 1):

```
var personString = "<Person><Name>Person Name</Name></Person>"; // Your XML string

var restClient = new RestClient("http://localhost:56453/api/people");

var restRequest = new RestRequest("Post", Method.POST);

restRequest.RequestFormat = DataFormat.Xml;
restRequest.AddParameter("application/xml", personString, ParameterType.RequestBody);
var response = restClient.Execute(restRequest);
```

Don't forget to add folloing code in WebApiConfig.cs

```
config.Formatters.XmlFormatter.UseXmlSerializer = true;
```